# Clear fish shell/WSL Console scrolling line history?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish

I use the Fish shell (version 3.1.0) as my daily driver, it's running under Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 1.

I have a minor annoyance with this setup:

Let's say I run a shell script or run a command that outputs hundreds or thousands of lines to the console.

If I hit `control + l`, I can reset the console to a clean view. But if I were to scroll up, I still see the history. Sometimes this is great! But sometimes I need to run the same command multiple times, and it's hazardous to have previous runs in the history to accidentally scroll into. (I might think I'm seeing result X, but that's from an older run!)

Is there some way to tell either Fish or the WSL console to clear the line-history(?) so I get a completely blank view, so I cannot scroll upwards? I don't want this on all the time, but it would be useful as a keybind to clear it periodically.

I am not certain whether this responsibility falls under the shell or console, and what exactly this kind of history is called. Feel free to correct the post if you know these details.

Also: To be clear, I do not want to clear the *command/input* history. I don't want what commands I ran to vanish, those are important. Just the results need to go away.

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` command seems to do what I want. Not sure if I can make a shortcut for it under WSL.